# Number of comments with SocialCommentManager.GetComments

Tags: 2010, social, social-note

In my custom webpart, I want to show the number of comments. I try to get this throug SocialCommentManager.GetComments and then return comments.Count.

The problem is: I get only comments for the current user. Say, there are three comments on a page, one is mine. On startpage in a custom webpart I see that there is only one comment.

Even if I run with elevated, the users get only the number of their comments.

```
int number;
SocialComment[] comments = null;
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate
     {
         using (SPSite esite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID))
         {
             var sc = SPServiceContext.GetContext(esite);
             var soc = new SocialCommentManager(sc);
             comments = soc.GetComments(uri, maxNumberOfComments);
             number = comments.Count();
         }
});
```

While logged in as System Account, I get all (System Account is set as the [administrator on User Profile Service](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/b35ab649-5b61-42d3-8eb2-782704481150/)).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution: You must renew the [HttpContext](http://socialsp.com/tag/sharepoint-2010/).

```
int number;
SocialComment[] comments = null;    
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate
         {
             using (SPSite esite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID))
             {
                 var ctx = HttpContext.Current;
                 try
                 {
                     Log.Info("Trying to get comments");                                                             
                     var sc = SPServiceContext.GetContext(esite);
                     HttpContext.Current = null;
                     var soc = new SocialCommentManager(sc);
                     comments = soc.GetComments(uri, maxNumberOfComments);
                     number = comments.Count();
                 }
                 catch (Exception ex)
                 {
                     Log.Error(ex);
                 }
                 finally
                 {
                     HttpContext.Current = ctx;
                 }            
             }
    });
```

Comment: I am accepting my own solution. If someone finds out how to solve it a better way, I'll accept the new solution with a great pleasure.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the override with the Uri.

Check here please.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.socialdata.socialcommentmanager.getcomments.aspx

Comment: if you see the documentation the getcomments has different override methods, meaning different parameters can be passed, check the one that only passes the Uri without user and you will get all the comments for that uri regardless of the user.