# Comments are not getting displayed on the SharePoint 2010 page

Tags: social, tagging, social-tag

we are using a SharePoint out of box feature to comment on the page. Comments are getting displayed if end user posts the comments however it is not getting displayed(for end users) if the comments are posted by a farm account.

Is that an expected behavior? How to solve this?

Comment: What do you mean by a "farm account"? Are you talking about one of the service accounts?

Comment: yes, i meant the service account.

Comment: any help in understanding the architecture of social notes and comments. 

What are the pre requirements to configure the out of comments? 

Why it is not displaying the comments when end users added the comments?

Do we need to crawl the contents to show the comments?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what exact OOB feature you are using, to help people investigate?

Comment: We do something like this, but we needed to actually give permissions to the list for the comments to be viewable by others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Privacy and security implications of social tagging (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff608006.aspx) can help you some understanding as to how the security trimming worked on Notes web part. Following is taken from it:

> Security trimming
>
> Adding a tag, a note, or a rating to a Web page creates an activity.
>   Before SharePoint Server displays an activity, it uses a component
>   called the security trimmer to determine whether the current user has
>   permission to view the Web page that the activity applies to. If the
>   user is not permitted to view the Web page, SharePoint Server does not
>   display the activity.
>
> As the search service crawls Web pages, it records the permissions
>   that are required to view each Web page. The security trimmer uses
>   this information to determine whether a given user has permission to
>   view a specific Web page. If the security trimmer has insufficient
>   information to determine whether a user has permission to view a Web
>   page, it errs on the side of caution and reports that the user does
>   not have permission to view the Web page. As a result, if the search
>   service has not crawled a Web page, activities that relate to that Web
>   page will not be displayed.

Comment: thanks for your help, I understood that crawling plays an important role while working with social comments. In our environment, we have configured AAM for a given webapplication, say, the webapplication's default public zone url is https://test.url.com and its internal url is http://servername:82, is it fine to use the internal url to crawl? whereus users are using the default url to post the comments?...or it is mandatory to crawl the default url?

Comment: Since the crawling, requests and trimming are all done on URLs, I would imagine it's best if they all match.

Comment: Thanks for your help. steps: 1. Verify the access "search account" access permission on the webapplicaton 2. Post a comment 3. Crawl the page (URL should be the same one where you have posted your comment, AAM won't help) 4. browse the page, it should display the comments.

Comment: Perfect. I am disappointed with Microsoft for your finding that AAM does not help.

Answer (score 0):

[This man suggests some valid work-arounds to this issue](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sanjaynarang/archive/2011/06/12/custom-note-board-web-part-socialcommentmanager-social-security-trimming-and-search.aspx).
I had the same challenge with a project for my company and used some of his work-arounds to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this blog](http://www.stefanopaterno.com/post/2012/02/08/Social-Comments-e-Security-Trimming.aspx) were they resolve this by code:

```
var type = typeof(SocialCommentManager);
var methods = type.GetMethods(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
var method = methods.FirstOrDefault(m => m.ToString() == "Microsoft.Office.Server.SocialData.SocialComment[] GetComments(System.Uri, Int32, Int32, System.DateTime, Boolean)");
if (method == null) throw new MissingMethodException("Social GetComment method not found.");
var comments = method.Invoke(cm, new object[] { uri, 10000, 0, DateTime.MinValue, false }) as SocialComment[];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where I wanted [to get a number of comments in code](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/20389/number-of-comments-with-socialcommentmanager-getcomments/20453#20453). Comments are security-trimmed. Try to set the [app pool account as Social Data Administrator](http://sharepointkunskap.wordpress.com/2011/09/22/get-all-comments/): Central Administration -> Application Management -> Service Applications -> User Profile Services.